# deploy to openshift, got Error: Attempt to unlock async@*, which hasn't been locked

Tags: openshift

git push openshift master, then got this error. use diy-0.1, the codebase is https://github.com/onepiecejs/nodejs-cantas, it can directly deploy to openshift online. Does anyone can give me a hint?

```
remote:   - Installing dependencies w/ new version of npm ...
remote:
remote: npm info it worked if it ends with ok
remote: npm info using npm@1.4.3
remote: npm info using node@v0.10.26
remote: npm info preinstall cantas@1.0.0
remote: npm ERR! Error: Attempt to unlock connect-redis@1.4.x, which hasn't been locked
remote: npm ERR!     at unlock (/var/lib/openshift/536769dd500446ba9c00014f/app-root/data/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:1304:11)
remote: npm ERR!     at cb (/var/lib/openshift/536769dd500446ba9c00014f/app-root/data/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:646:5)
remote: npm ERR!     at /var/lib/openshift/536769dd500446ba9c00014f/app-root/data/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:655:20
remote: npm ERR!     at /var/lib/openshift/536769dd500446ba9c00014f/app-root/data/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:1282:20
remote: npm ERR!     at afterMkdir (/var/lib/openshift/536769dd500446ba9c00014f/app-root/data/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:1013:14)
remote: npm ERR!     at /var/lib/openshift/536769dd500446ba9c00014f/app-root/data/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
remote: npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
remote: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
remote: npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
remote: npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

....
```

Answer (score 0):

I use alternative step overcome the issue.

upgrade hook_action/lib/utils by new reop:
https://github.com/ramr/nodejs-custom-version-openshift

use ndoe-0.10 cartridge instead of diy-0.1, then redeploy again. it got things done.